# knockout Validation message displaying twice?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I been used to do validation using knockout validation plugin and all of a sudden i am facing a issue i am unable to get rid of .

**Html onLoad :**

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value:$data.Name"/>
<span class="required" style="display: none;"></span>
<span class="required" style="display: none;"></span>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
function details() {
    var self =this;
    self.Name = ko.observable("");
    self.Validation = ko.validatedObservable([
        self.Name.extend({ number: true })
    ]);
}
```

When i removed `self.Name.extend` i get `no` span tags onLoad but if i keep it then i get two span tags and because of that i get same error messages displaying twice under control like `this field is required` & `this field is required` .

I also debugged and checked the function is excecuting only once .

I refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399928/knockout-validation-showing-same-error-message-twice) but i can't fix my issue .

I hope someone can show light on this issue .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credits to  `Hsakarp` as he posted a valuable comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399928/knockout-validation-showing-same-error-message-twice)

One of my partail page is referred with knockout validation.js and i am had same validation file in my main layout page . I have't noticed the script file added by my colleague .

Finally , i tried to see `View Source` then i came to see clearly there are two knockout validation script files referred of same kind . so i removed one of those which is included in partial view which got my issue fixed .